# Menu Structure and Loops

Tags: c++

I have this little program I am creating. In lamens terms, I am wanting to make a menu where a user can input his selection, it takes him to the predetermined area and after he is done it takes him back to the menu where he can make a different selection. I have gotten down where it displays when you press 1 (you will see what i mean with the code). But after it goes through what it is supposed to do, it doesn't go back to the menu it just continues on to the second option. Also say you are at the menu and you want to start with the 2nd option it just starts with the first. Can anyone please help me with this...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int option;

    cout << "Hello there...\n\nToday we are going to do a little fun project that I created.\n\n";
    cin.get();

    cout << "\nAs we progress throughout this program, I will explain the different things\n";
    cout << "that we are going to do. We will be covering some basic C++ excersises.";
    cout << "\n\nFirst and foremost we will  begin by  covering what I have learned so far....\n\n";
    cin.get();

    cout << "The first topic we will cover will include what is known as 'variables'.\n";
    cout << "what are variables you ask?";
    cin.get();


    int var = 1;
    int main=1;
        do
        {
            cout << "\n\n\nEnter the number of one of the following and I will explain!\n";
            cout << "1.integer  2.boolian   3.floats   4.doubles   5.character";
            cout << "\n\n[when you are done type 'done' to continue]\n\n";
            cin >> option; //this is where the user puts in his option (1,2,3,4,5,6) I have only 1 and 2 complete

            if (option = 1) //starts with this regardless of input
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\n\n\nInteger is the variable abbreviated as 'int' this allows C++ to only";
                cout << "\nread whole and real numbers. C++ takes this number as stores it\n";
                cout << "in a user-defined variable (you can make up what that variable is..)\n";
                cin.get();
                cout << "an example syntax would be:";
                cout << "\n\nint var=[whole;real number]";
                cin.get();
                cout << "\n\nwhat this implies is that you have 'declared' to the system";
                cout << "\nthat you are going to use an 'int' that you have named 'var'\n";
                cout << "and in this 'var' you are going to store a real and whole number\ninside of it.";
                cout << "\n\nPress any key to go back to menu";
                cin.get();
            }
            else if (option = 2); //continues with this without going back to menu.
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\n\n\nBoolian is the variable abbreviated as 'bool' this allows C++ to only";
                cout << "\nread true or false ( 0 or 1 ). C++ takes this number as stores it\n";
                cout << "in a user-defined variable (you can make up what that variable is..)\n";
                cin.get();
                cout << "an example syntax would be:";
                cout << "\n\nbool var=[true or false]";
                cin.get();
                cout << "\n\nwhat this implies is that you have 'declared' to the system";
                cout << "\nthat you are going to use an 'bool' variable that you have named 'var'\n";
                cout << "and in this 'var' you are going to store a either a true or false\ninside of it.";
                cout << "\n\nPress any key to go back to menu";
                cin.get();
            }

        } while (var = 1);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the comparison operator

1) `if (option = 1)`  , use `if(option == 1)`

2) `else if (option = 2);`   , use `else if(option == 2)` , remove the semicolon

3) `while(var = 1) ;` , use `while(var ==1 );`

Answer (score 0):

comparision in C++ is done with the == operator:

e.g.

```
 if (option == 1) 
 if (option == 2) 
 while (var == 1);
```